# Track user connections to server over a specific period

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, connection

I am looking to obtain information on users who are conencted to a specific server over a length of time - say a week.

I know I can view all current users conencted through sysprocesses however we really need to create a log of all users, when they were connected and to which database they connected to.

It is a SQL 2000 server we are using.

Is this even possible and if so how?

Thanks
Ross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server has supported C2 level auditing since 2000.   That should do what you are expecting it to.

This article should get you started.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277388.aspx